# Show that $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ converges uniformly to $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Show that there is a sequence of functions continuously differentiable $f_{n}:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $f_{n}$ converges uniformly to $0$ but $f'_{n}$ not converges to $0$.

Take
$$f_{n}(x) = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}.$$
So,
$$f'_{n}(x) = x^{n},$$
and
$f'_{n} \to f$ pointwise where $f$ is the function
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0,&\text{if}\;\;x \in [0,1)\\ 1,& \text{if}\;\; x=1.\end{cases}.$$
Is obvious that $f_{n} \to 0$ pointwise, but I couldn't show that the convergence is uniform.

Comment: Hint. $|f_n|\leqslant 1/(n+1)$

Comment: @xbh, oh... of course!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$. There exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\, 1/(n+1) < \epsilon \,$ for every $n \geq N$. Then for every such $n$ it follows that

$$ |f_{n}(x)-0| = \frac{|x|^{n+1}}{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{n+1} < \epsilon$$

for every $x \in [0,1]$: we have just verified the very definition of uniform convergence here.